# Adding a value to a TextInput changes the font-weight for some reason

Tags: react-native, react-native-textinput, react-native-stylesheet

I'm trying to format the date while the user is typing but when I add the value field (value={this.state.dob}) the style changes for a bolder font-weight (and sometimes changes for the right font weight mid typing). It really seems to come from the value field I tried adding it to other Input from this page and it does the same thing.

```
  <TextInput
        placeholder="JJ/MM/AAAA"
        keyboardType={'number-pad'}
        onChangeText={(text) => this._onChangeDate(text)}
        name="dob"
        style={styles.textBox}
        value={this.state.dob} //Just removing this work but I can't liveformat the date anymore 
        maxLength={10}
   />

_onChangeDate = (value) => {
    this.setState({
        dob: this.liveFormatDate(value),
    })  

}
```

liveFormatDate returns a  string add slashes when needed discards letters and so on

[How it looks right now](https://i.stack.imgur.com/85PNz.png)

[How it should look like (when there are 6 characters it looks like this)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H2b2D.png)
I didn't modify the code between the two screeshots

Comment: Hmm i use the same pattern for formatting phone numbers as the user types and havent seen the same issue. How are you creating your styles? Are you using `StyleSheet.create`?

Comment: Hi I have solved the problem by adding a font-weight attribute in the style (font-weight:"normal" which is the default value if I'm not mistaken.) So the behaviour is really weird.

Comment: Excellent!! Glad you figured it out :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution was to add the weight attribute in the style (`font-weight: "normal"`). Though I don't know why the font weight was changing constantly I don't know what was causing this.